# Jmeter - groovy function not working as expected

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have a groovy function which performs some date operations. i.e. Returns a date 12 months forward. This date is encoded and stored into a variable.

snippet:

```
${__groovy(import groovy.time.TimeCategory; def now = new Date(); use(TimeCategory) { def nowPlusOneYear = now + 12.month - 1.day; return URLEncoder.encode(nowPlusOneYear.format('dd/MM/YYYY')\, 'UTF-8')},Policy_ExpiryDate)}
```

The above code works well with a JSR223 Sampler. Also, the variable name and its value gets displayed in debug sampler.

But, when I use this code along with a GET HTTP Request. The value doesn't gets substituted.

the request:

```
/IIMS/target/source/UNDERWRITING/ValidatorAction.action?dataString=%7B%22Testing%22%3A%22F%22%2C%22VCURRENTSTATUSNAME%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Entry%20Date%22%3A%22${__urlencode(${__time(dd/MM/YYYY,Entry_Date)})}%22%2C%22Policy%20Type%22%3A%22FLEET%22%2C%22Policy%20Inception%20Date%22%3A%22${__urlencode(${__time(dd/MM/YYYY,Policy_InceptionDate)})}%22%2C%22Policy%20Inception%20Time%22%3A%22${__urlencode(${__time(HH:mm:ss,Policy_InceptionTime)})}%22%2C%22Policy%20Duration%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22Unit%22%3A%22F%22%2C%22Policy%20Expiry%20Date%22%3A%22${__groovy(import groovy.time.TimeCategory; def now = new Date(); use(TimeCategory) { def nowPlusOneYear = now + 12.month - 1.day; return URLEncoder.encode(nowPlusOneYear.format('dd/MM/YYYY')\, 'UTF-8')},Policy_ExpiryDate)}%22%2C%22Policy%20Expiry%20Time%22%3A%2223%3A59%3A59%22%2C%22Type%20Of%20Business%22%3A%22CASH%22%2C%22Payment%20Frequency%22%3A%22B%22%2C%22Country%22%3A%22UAE%22%2C%22Source%20of%20Business%22%3A%220DIR%22%2C%22Policy%20branch%22%3A%22${UserDetails_g5}%22%2C%22UMR%20Number%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Equator%20Policy%22%3A%22N%22%2C%22Policy%20holder%22%3A%22${PolicyHolderDetails_g1}%22%2C%22Policy%20holderNew%22%3A%22${PolicyHolderDetails_g2}%22%2C%22SEC-POLPLANNumber%20of%20Vehicles%20in%20Fleet%22%3A%220%22%2C%22SEC-POLPLANPolicy%20Plan%22%3A%22NA%22%2C%22SEC-POLPLANDistribution%20Channel%22%3A%22DIROIC%22%2C%22SEC-POLPLANName%20of%20the%20Scheme%22%3A%22NA%22%2C%22SEC-PLRIDPolicy%20Level%20FAC%20R%2FI%22%3A%22N%22%2C%22SEC-PLRIDPolicy%20Level%20FAC%20R%2FI%20percentage%22%3A%220%22%2C%22SEC-PLRIDPolicy%20Level%20Proportional%20FAC%20R%2FI%20percentage%22%3A%220%22%2C%22SEC-PLRIDPolicy%20Level%20Non%20Proportional%20FAC%20R%2FI%20percentage%22%3A%220%22%2C%22SEC-PLRIDProp%20Non%20Prop%20FAC%20Date%22%3A%22Y%22%2C%22SEC-CEDANTNumber%20of%20Cedants%20Involved%22%3A%22%22%2C%22SEC-CEDANTCedant%20Country%22%3A%22%22%2C%22SEC-MDPMinimum%20Deposit%20Premium%20Applicable%22%3A%22N%22%2C%22SEC-MDPMinimum%20Deposit%20Premium%20Type%22%3A%22%22%2C%22SEC-MDPPercentage%20of%20Premium%22%3A%22%22%2C%22SEC-MDPMinimum%20Deposit%20Premium%22%3A%22%22%2C%22SEC-MDPMinimum%20premium%22%3A%22%22%2C%22SEC-CRMCRM%20Reference%20Number%22%3A%22${__Random(1111111,9999999,CRM_RefNo)}%22%2C%22pBusinessTranCode%22%3A%22SCR-BSCDTL%22%2C%22pSaveContinueIndicator%22%3A%22%22%2C%22pJSPName%22%3A%22BasicInformation.jsp%22%2C%22crtPartyFunctionInd%22%3A%22Y%22%2C%22strTOC%22%3A%22%22%2C%22existingPartyIndicator%22%3A%22Y%22%2C%22disabledSectionCode%22%3A%22%22%2C%22scriptaculous%22%3A%22%22%2C%22language%22%3A%22null%22%2C%22policyId%22%3A%22null%22%2C%22policyPlanUpgradation%22%3A%22N%22%2C%22reason%22%3A%22%22%2C%22isMasterQuote%22%3A%22FALSE%22%2C%22USERCODE%22%3A%22${UserDetails_g6}%22%2C%22pVersionDate%22%3A%22%22%2C%22__endorsementType%22%3A%22null%22%2C%22cSystemDate%22%3A%22${__urlencode(${__time(dd/MM/YYYY,cSystemDate)})}%22%2C%22cedantEndrDate%22%3A%2208%2F12%2F2117%22%2C%22CIMS_CSRFTOKEN%22%3A%22${CIMS_CSRFTOKEN}%22%7D%3B&productCode=0101&productId=1030885614052014
```

All values get substituted properly except for the groovy part. Am I missing something over here. The debug sampler doesn't shows a variable named Policy_ExpiryDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

__groovy() works well with Jmeter 5.4. But this function is not recognized in Jmeter 5.3.

Thanks a lot for your help @Dmitri T

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue, __groovy() function is normally getting evaluated and the substituted by its respective value:

[image]

If it doesn't for you - most probably it fails somewhere somehow, check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries

Also you can execute the function anywhere else, for example in [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) configuration element and refer the value where required just as `${Policy_ExpiryDate}`

[image]